# Entry field with submit button in python?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I would like to make a password and username entry field. And a "submit" button on the bottom.
This is what i have got so far but i cant figure out how to work with the grid:

So this is the code that will create 1 entry field, names "username"

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.pack( side = LEFT)
E1 = Entry(top, bd =5)
E1.pack(side = RIGHT)
top.mainloop()
```

and this is my code for the submit button:

```
MyButton1 = Button(master, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton1.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

I just don't know how to put these two codes together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, don't mix `pack` and `grid`.

Second, your button has a different parent than your entry. Replace `master` with `top`.
And don't forget to actually implement your `callback` function, or it won't work.

```
from Tkinter import *

def callback():
    print 'You clicked the button!'

top = Tk()
L1 = Label(top, text="User Name")
L1.grid(row=0, column=0)
E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)
E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

MyButton1 = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback)
MyButton1.grid(row=1, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: so you recommend using the grid instead of pack?

Comment: @VincenTTTTTTTTTTTT: Yes, `grid` allows you much more control than `pack`.